# Stretch one element in height, but not the other

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a row with flex-elements with `align-items: stretch`. They are the same height, which is what I need.

```css
        html,body{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .container{
            width: 500px;
        }

        .items{
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
        }

        .item{
            width: 40%;
            margin: 0 10px;
        }

        .content{
            background: #808080;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .btn{
            padding: 5px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="items">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="title">long-long<br>title</div>
                    <div class="title">desc</div>
                    <div class="price">price</div>
                </div>
                <div class="btn">btn</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="title">title</div>
                    <div class="title">desc</div>
                    <div class="price">price</div>
                </div>
                <div class="btn">btn</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="title">title</div>
                    <div class="title">desc</div>
                    <div class="price">price</div>
                </div>
                <div class="btn">btn</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The question is:

How can I do this, the height of all content blocks was the same and equal to the largest of them, but the height of the buttons and the indent between the button and the content were fixed

**EDIT**

It looks like it's easier to show the result I want to achieve visually

What I get:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: @Paulie_D edited.

Comment: are you trying to position the buttons so they are aligned horizontally?  Your question is still not clear

Comment: Please explain what should grow in your case. If the gap between content and button should stay consistent, then should the button height increse?

Comment: @AndrisJefimovs No, оnly the height of the gray block should increase

Comment: add `height: calc(100% - 37px);` to `content` class.

Comment: `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` on `.item` and `flex-grow: 1;` on `.content`

Comment: @AndrisJefimovs Thank you!

Comment: @Oleg I'm glad I could help